# Spring startup performance significantly slower when beans are nested inside jar

Tags: spring

We have thousands of Spring beans in our web app and we're using Spring release 4.2.4.  We recently changed our packaging scheme and noticed that our application startup time got way slower when the Spring beans being loaded were nested inside jars.

When profiling, we found the hotspot to be at the enclosed stack trace where every candidate bean resulted in a new inputstream created into the jar.  This was occurring inside org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider#findCandidateComponents where it is iterating through each resource and getting a MetadataReader.

The only way we could find to work-around was to change our packaging scheme such that our spring beans were not in jars and were exploded in to the webapp's WEB-INF/classes directory.

I searched around and was surprised that I couldn't find others having experienced this problem.   Anyone know if this is something Spring is tracking as a bug?  Or is it just best practice that heavy use of Spring means that classes should be exploded in to the webapp's WEB-INF/classes directory?

```
"localhost-startStop-1" #21 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f289c3c1800 nid=0x6bb5 runnable [0x00007f28c94c2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:355)
        - eliminated <0x00000000f2ae2240> (a sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:447)
        - locked <0x00000000f2ae2240> (a sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:162)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:168)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        - locked <0x00000000b445f1a8> (a org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory$1)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:279)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
        - locked <0x00000000b4484ac0> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
```

Answer (score 1):

I never experienced this behavior, and I always pack beans into jars (but not thousands of them..).

The CachingMetadataReaderFactory should cache the metadata per resource to avoid opening the same jar many times.

It has a default cache limit of 256 (resources). May be this is to low in your case ?

You can change this by creating your own CachingMetadataReaderFactory bean and increasing the limit.

Or you can set some breakpoints in that class, to see when entries from the cache are evicted or cache entries are not found.

Comment: Can you help me replace the default CachingMetadataReaderFactory by my own ?  I cant figure out how I should configure spring to use my own CachingMetadataReaderFactory.